# Local mongodb with Compose.io as replica set?

Tags: mongodb, compose-db

Basically, I'm considering this:

A local MongoDB server backed up by Compose.io.  So Compose handles HA, backups, etc - but I get the speed of a local MongoDB instance.

Is this possible/sane?  Would this actually solve the HA/backups problem, or just complicate it?

I have two DigitalOcean servers, but not the ops experience managing MongoDB.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @johnc, I did not find a recipe for this.  MongoDB has an article you might like: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/replica-set-architecture-geographically-distributed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I have to this is to create a local instance of mongo and periodically back it up and restore it to compose.io and basically keep the two in sync. There are a few projects we are looking at

- https://github.com/tutumcloud/mongodb-backup
- https://hub.docker.com/r/agaveapi/mongodb-sync/